# Dynamic UITextField creation

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is it possible to create dynamic `UITextField` like when user clicks text field for edit, it automatically creates another `UITextField` below that `UITextField`.

Comment: use code which i post in answer for create dynamic textfield exact under your textfield when textfield begin edit..

Comment: don't ask for any example. try it in your own way using given hint

Comment: You need to improve your searching capabilities...stack overflow contains dozens of example regarding "How to create dynamically objects".

Comment: @Debabrata , my code is directly use for you with your textfield condition.. you try this code or not??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{    

      if(textField == firstTextFeild){

          //Create secondTextFeild.
   }

}
```

Comment: secondTextFeild frame should be like secondTextFeild.frame = CGRectMake(firstTextFeild.frame.origin.x, (firstTextFeild.frame.origin.y + firstTextFeild.frame.size.height) + 10, firstTextFeild.frame.size.width, firstTextFeild.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

Create a new textField Like:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,210,265,30)];
myTextField.placeholder=@"Enter Label Here";
myTextField.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
myTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[self.view addSubView:myTextField];
```

You need to change the frame according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here in the

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Allocate another `UITextField` according to the frame of the original `UITextField` and if you want to add multiple textfields put the allocation in a loop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your .m file or just add bellow code in your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    UITextField *txtTemp=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yourTextField.frame.origin.x, yourTextField.frame.origin.y + 50, yourTextField.frame.size.width, yourTextField.frame.size.height)];
    txtTemp.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:txtTemp];
    return YES;
}
```